# Wonach bestimmt sich hier das Geschlecht des Pronomens?

Tags: pronoun

In der aktuellen ZEIT steht der Satz:

> Sophia ist ein quirliges Mädchen mit Zopf und Micky-Maus-Shirt und mit **seinen** bald vier Jahren [..]

Wäre es genauso richtig zu schreiben "[..] und mit **ihren** bald [..]". Oder bezieht sich der Satz immer auf "Mädchen", also eigentlich auf das Objekt? Gibt es da eine klare Regel?

Comment: Dein Zitat ist unvollständig! Ich vermute sehr stark, dass das Subjekt, auf das sich *seinen* bezieht, erst noch folgt, z.B. "... mit seinen bald vier Jahren geht **das Kind** ...". Folgt kein weiteres Subjekt, ist *seinen* hier falsch! Richtig wäre dann: "Sophia ist ... und mit **ihren** bald vier Jahren schon recht groß."

Comment: Es wurde vorgeschlagen, die Frage wieder zu öffnen, weil das angegebene Duplikat anders gelagert sein könnte. Ich begrüßen, zuerst das Zitat zu komplettieren, um das dann entscheiden zu können.